# Создание блока, с 3 картинками внутри и наполненным теском, но 2 картинка смещается

Tags: html, css

```
Html      
<div class="table-plan">
          <div class="table1">
            <img class="img-table1" src="images/book-img.png" alt="">
            <h3 class="title-table1">Student</h3>
            <h3 class="price-table1">39</h3>
            <ul class="list-table1">
              <li class="item-table1">6 GB storage</li>
              <li class="item-table1">Fast Brandwidht</li>
              <li class="item-table1">Responsive</li>
              <li class="item-table1">Customization</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="button-sign">Sign up</a>
          </div>
          <div class="table2">
            <img class="img-table2" src="images/case-img.png" alt="">
            <h3 class="title-table2">Professional</h3>
            <h3 class="price-table2">59</h3>
            <ul class="list-table2">
              <li class="item-table2">6 GB storage</li>
              <li class="item-table2">Fast Brandwidht</li>
              <li class="item-table2">Responsive</li>
              <li class="item-table2">Customization</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="button-sign1">Sign up</a>
          </div>
        <div class="table3">
            <img class="img-table1" src="images/bag-plan.png" alt="">
            <h3 class="title-table1">Unlimited</h3>
            <h3 class="price-table1">99</h3>
            <ul class="list-table1">
              <li class="item-table1">6 GB storage</li>
              <li class="item-table1">Fast Brandwidht</li>
              <li class="item-table1">Responsive</li>
              <li class="item-table1">Customization</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="button-sign">Sign up</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>-->
CSS
.table-plan{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.table1{
  background-image: url("images/bg-table1.png");
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 320px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.title-table1{
  font-family: 'Raleway Bold', arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.price-table1{
  font-family: 'Raleway ExtraBold', arial;
  font-size: 72px;
  color:#3BBFEF;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}
.price-table1::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "$";
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 100px;
  top:20px;
}
.price-table1::after{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "/mo";
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 75px;
  top:50px;
}
.list-table1{
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Raleway Medium', arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}
.list-table1:last-child{
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.item-table1{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.item-table1:last-child{
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.button-sign{
  padding: 20px 34px 20px 47px;
  background-color: #66D4F4;
  border-radius: 25%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  cursor: pointer;  
}
.table2{
  background-image: url("images/bg-table2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 66px 0 47px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 355px;
}

.title-table1{
  font-family: 'Raleway Bold', arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.price-table2{
  font-family: 'Raleway ExtraBold', arial;
  font-size: 80px;
  color:#3BBFEF;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}
.price-table2::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "$";
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 110px;
  top:20px;
}
.price-table2::after{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "/mo";
  font-size: 20px;
  right: 75px;
  top:60px;
}
.list-table2{
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Raleway Medium', arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
}
.list-table2:last-child{
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.item-table2{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.item-table1:last-child{
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.button-sign1{
  padding: 20px 34px 20px 47px;
  background-color: #66D4F4;
  border-radius: 25%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fff;
  cursor: pointer;  
  font-size: 16px;
}
.table3{
  background-image: url("images/bg-table1.png");
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 320px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHNPg.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы для `<div class="table1">`в стилях задайте`margin-right: 50px` из-за чего ширина первого элемента увеличивается, и соответственно `<div class="table2">` смещается. 
Если отступ важен для сохранения промежутка при адаптации, добавьте и с другой стороны отступ. (лучше задать по бокам отступ для `<div class="table2">`